# extracting lines with pivot column

Tags: awk

Infile,

```
S   235 1365    *   0   *   *   *   15  1   c81 592
H   235 296 99.7    +   0   0   3I296M1066I 14  1   s15018  1
H   235 719 95.4    +   0   0   174D545M820I    15  1   c2664   10
H   235 764 99.1    +   0   0   55I764M546I 15  1   c6519   4
H   235 792 100 +   0   0   180I792M393I    14  1   c407    107
S   236 1365    *   0   *   *   *   15  1   c474    152
H   236 279 95  +   0   0   765I279M321I    10-1    1   s7689   1
H   236 301 99.7    -   0   0   908I301M156I    15  1   s8443   1
H   236 563 95.2    -   0   0   728I563M74I 17  1   c1725   12
H   236 97  97.9    -   0   0   732I97M536I 17  1   s11472  1
S   237 1365    *   0   *   *   *   15  1   c474    152
H   237 279 95  +   0   0   765I279M321I    15    1   s7689   1
S   238 1365    *   0   *   *   *   12  1   c474    152
H   238 279 95  +   0   0   765I279M321I    10-1    1   s7689   1
H   238 301 99.7    -   0   0   908I301M156I    15  1   s8443   1
H   238 563 95.2    -   0   0   728I563M74I 17  1   c1725   12
H   238 97  97.9    -   0   0   732I97M536I 17  1   s11472  1
```

Outfile what I want is below,

Example 1 by specifying ninth column "10-1", "15", and "17".

```
S   236 1365    *   0   *   *   *   15  1   c474    152
H   236 279 95  +   0   0   765I279M321I    10-1    1   s7689   1
H   236 301 99.7    -   0   0   908I301M156I    15  1   s8443   1
H   236 563 95.2    -   0   0   728I563M74I 17  1   c1725   12
H   236 97  97.9    -   0   0   732I97M536I 17  1   s11472  1
```

Example 2 by specifying ninth column "14" and "15".

```
S   235 1365    *   0   *   *   *   15  1   c81 592
H   235 296 99.7    +   0   0   3I296M1066I 14  1   s15018  1
H   235 719 95.4    +   0   0   174D545M820I    15  1   c2664   10
H   235 764 99.1    +   0   0   55I764M546I 15  1   c6519   4
H   235 792 100 +   0   0   180I792M393I    14  1   c407    107
```

Example 3 by specifying ninth column "15".

```
S   237 1365    *   0   *   *   *   15  1   c474    152
H   237 279 95  +   0   0   765I279M321I    15    1   s7689   1
```

So I would like to extract set of lines those have same value in the second column. At this time, I need to extract only set of lines which have specific values in 9th column. In that case, the set of lines need to have "all of the specified values".

The set 238 has "12" in the ninth column, which is not specified. So I do not want them to be extracted.

This question is very similar to this question. 
[Extracting lines using two criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219165/extracting-lines-using-two-criteria)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many possible approaches but IMHO the most robust and easiest to expand upon later is to create a hash table of the desired values (`goodVals[]` below) and then just test if the current `$9` is a value that's not in that table:

```
BEGIN { split("10-1 15 17",tmp); for (i in tmp) goodVals[tmp[i]] }
$2 != prevPivot { prtCurrSet() }
!($9 in goodVals) { isBadSet=1 }
{ currSet = currSet $0 ORS; prevPivot = $2 }
END { prtCurrSet() }
function prtCurrSet() {
    if ( !isBadSet ) {
        printf "%s", currSet
    }
    currSet = ""
    isBadSet = 0
}
```

Given the new requirement from your comment, here's a solution for one possible interpretation of that requirement:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { split("10-1 15 17",tmp); for (i in tmp) goodVals[tmp[i]] }
$2 != prevPivot { prtCurrSet() }
{ seen[$9]; currSet = currSet $0 ORS; prevPivot = $2 }
END { prtCurrSet() }
function prtCurrSet(    val,allGoodPresent) {
    allGoodPresent = 1
    for (val in goodVals) {
        if ( !(val in seen) ) {
            allGoodPresent = 0
        }
    }
    if ( allGoodPresent ) {
        printf "%s", currSet
    }
    currSet = ""
    delete seen
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
S   236 1365    *   0   *   *   *   15  1   c474    152
H   236 279 95  +   0   0   765I279M321I    10-1    1   s7689   1
H   236 301 99.7    -   0   0   908I301M156I    15  1   s8443   1
H   236 563 95.2    -   0   0   728I563M74I 17  1   c1725   12
H   236 97  97.9    -   0   0   732I97M536I 17  1   s11472  1
```

and here's another:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { split("10-1 15 17",tmp); for (i in tmp) goodVals[tmp[i]] }
$2 != prevPivot { prtCurrSet() }
{ seen[$9]; currSet = currSet $0 ORS; prevPivot = $2 }
END { prtCurrSet() }
function prtCurrSet(    val,allGoodPresent,someBadPresent) {
    allGoodPresent = 1
    for (val in goodVals) {
        if ( !(val in seen) ) {
            allGoodPresent = 0
        }
        delete seen[val]
    }
    someBadPresent = length(seen)
    if ( allGoodPresent && !someBadPresent ) {
        printf "%s", currSet
    }
    currSet = ""
    delete seen
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
S   236 1365    *   0   *   *   *   15  1   c474    152
H   236 279 95  +   0   0   765I279M321I    10-1    1   s7689   1
H   236 301 99.7    -   0   0   908I301M156I    15  1   s8443   1
H   236 563 95.2    -   0   0   728I563M74I 17  1   c1725   12
H   236 97  97.9    -   0   0   732I97M536I 17  1   s11472  1
```

Unfortunately your posted sample input/output isn't adequate to test the differences.

Comment: Hi Ed, 
At this time, I would like to extract set of lines which has all of '10-1' '15' '17'.    For example, last two lines in above infile have only '15'. So I would like NOT to extract them.

Comment: Then edit your question to clarify your requirements. Include in your example the case where all desired values are present but undesirable values are also present so we can see how you want that case handled too. So you should have 3 input sets - 1) some good + some bad, 2) all good + no bad, 3) all good + some bad.